# Realizar varios insert a una tabla con los números que están dentro de una variable Varchar en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un procedimiento que tiene una variable de entrada **IN_idExamenPrecio** que es tipo **VARCHAR(255)** que contiene por ejemplo el valor de *'123,432,200,340'* estos números los quiero usar por separados ya que son el **idExamenPrecio** de la tabla **RegistroData**. Quisiera hacerlo por medio de un bucle para que se ejecute varias veces el insert pero desconozco la forma hacerlo en mysql.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE BDFutureLab.sp_insertar_RegistroData (
IN IN_idExamenPrecio varchar(255) // contiene los números o los IDs =>  '123,432,200,340'
)
BEGIN

/* Quiero ejecutar este insert varias veces según los números que están
   en la variable IN_idExamenPrecio */
INSERT INTO BDFutureLab.RegistroData
(
idExamenPrecio, //Donde se deben ingresar los numeros que vienen en el  IN_idExamenPrecio 
fechaRegistro,
fechaActualizacion,
horaRegistro,
horaActualizacion,
estado)
VALUES (_idExamenPrecio,CURDATE(),null,CURTIME(),null,1);


    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado solucionar mi problema aplicando un loop que se ejecuta varias veces según los números que están en la variable IN_idExamenPrecio los cuales los extraigo con la función SPLIT_STR esto me permite hacer varios insert en la tabla RegistroData según la cantidad de números que vengan en IN_idExamenPrecio.

Les comparto el código de la solución:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE BDFutureLab.sp_insertar_RegistroData (
IN IN_idExamenPrecio varchar(255) // contiene los números o los IDs =>  '123|432|200|340'
)
BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 0;
      DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
/* El Loop se ejecuta varias veces según los números que están
   en la variable IN_idExamenPrecio  esto me permite hacer varios insert segun la cantidad de IN_idExamenPrecio*/
    simple_loop: LOOP
             SET a=a+1;
             SET str = SPLIT_STR(IN_idExamenPrecio,"|",a);
             IF str='' THEN
                LEAVE simple_loop;
             END IF;
            INSERT INTO BDFutureLab.RegistroData
            (
            idExamenPrecio, //Donde se deben ingresar los numeros que vienen en el  IN_idExamenPrecio 
            fechaRegistro,
            fechaActualizacion,
            horaRegistro,
            horaActualizacion,
            estado)
            VALUES (str,CURDATE(),null,CURTIME(),null,1);

    END LOOP simple_loop;

    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```